# Firebase: Atomically pop random element from realtime database

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

My firebase realtime database begins with a small list of unique elements in arbitrary order. Users can fetch an element(s) from this list, atomically popping it from the database, such that no other user can possess the same element. Users can also return their popped element to the list. In this way, the elements currently held by users, and those left in the database, are conserved. The list is small enough (max `27` elements) that I can efficiently load the entire database contents into memory if needed.

I am struggling to express this behaviour into my web (pure javascript) firebase application. I have seen [firebase transactions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write#save_data_as_transactions), but I'm not sure how to use these such that the popped child is selected psuedo-randomly.

Here is an inadequate attempt which violates atomicity (users may end up popping/getting the same element)

```js
function popRandElem() {

    // fetch all elements currently in db list
    db.ref('list').get().then( (snap) => {

        // choose random element
        var elems = snap.val();
        var keys = Object.keys(elems);
        var choice = keys[ keys.length * Math.random() << 0 ];

        // remove chosen element from db
        db.ref('list').child(choice).remove();

        return elems[choice];
    }
}

myElem = popRandElem();
```

```js
function restoreElem() {
    db.ref('list').push(myElem);
    myElem = null;
}
```

How can I adapt this example such that `popRandElem` atomically pops from the database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turned out to be straightforward with transactions, using the optional second callback to obtain the successfully popped element.

```js
function popRandElemAsynch() {

    var choice = null;
  
    db.ref('list').transaction(

        // repeats with updated list until run without collision
        function( list ) {

            // discard previous repetition choice
            choice = null;

            // edge-case of list emptied during transac repeats 
            if (!list)
                return list;
      
            // choose and remember a random element
            var keys = Object.keys(list);
            choice = keys[ keys.length * Math.random() << 0 ];

            // remove the element
            delete list[choice];
            return list;
        },

        // runs once after above has run for final time
        function() {
        
            // choice is the final uniquely popped element
            // if it is null, list was emptied before collision-free pop
            someFunc(choice);
        },

        // don't trigger premature events from transaction retries
        false
    );
}
```